# Generate a random number of type NTL::ZZ in C++

Tags: c++, ntl

I know that `NTL::RandomBnd(NTL::ZZ &x, const NTL::ZZ &n)` will make a random number that less than `n`, and assign it to x.
But I want to implement a function `NTL::ZZ generate_random_number(NTL::ZZ a, NTL::ZZ b)` which returns a value that in range `[a,b]`
This is my code to implement the function

```cpp
NTL::ZZ generate_random_number(NTL::ZZ a, NTL::ZZ b)
{
    NTL::ZZ random_number = a;
    while(random_number < a)
        NTL::RandomBnd(random_number, b);
    return random_number;
}
```

When `a` is close to `b`, this function won't work fine.


Is there a way to optimize it or any other function to implement the function I need.
Sorry for my poor English and don't care about the end points of `[a,b]`

Comment: Generate a number less than `b - a` then add `a` to it to move it back to the range you want.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Good comment with one suggestion. Since requested range includes both a and b, the generated number should be `b-a+1` before a is added.

Comment: @doug Figured I'd be off by one somewhere, but hopefully the general idea makes sense.

Comment: @RetiredNinja lol. We are all so used to c++ ranges.

Comment: @RetiredNinja  OTOH, since he said he didn't care about the end points, getting a random number using `b-a-1` then adding `a+1` to it would work without either end point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, but the function can still be optimized to work better. One way to do this is reject sampling:

```cpp
NTL::ZZ generate_random_number(const NTL::ZZ &a, const NTL::ZZ &b)
{
    NTL::ZZ range = b - a + 1;  // Compute the range of the interval [a, b]
    NTL::ZZ random_number;

    do {
        random_number = a + NTL::RandomBnd(range);  // Generate a random number in the range [0, range-1] and add it to 'a'
    } while (random_number > b);  // Reject the random number if it's greater than 'b'

    return random_number;
}
```

This should make the function run a lot better, hope it helped!

Comment: Is the loop even needed? If the range is setup correctly then the generated number can never be greater than `b` to begin with.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau, yes, this way better `return NTL::RandomBnd(b - a + 1) + a`